# lift snippet: prefix not bound to a namespace

Tags: scala, lift

im just starting with lift and scala and have a problem i dont realy understand.

i have the folowing index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <lift:Members.list>
            <tr>
                <td><m:nick/></td>
            </tr>
        </lift:Members.list>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following snippet:

```
class Members {
  def list(xhtml: NodeSeq) =
  Member.findAll.flatMap(member => bind("m",xhtml
                                       ,"nick" -> member.nickName
    ))
}
```

for some reason i get the following error. ive tried alot of things but cant get it to work. whats wrong?

```
XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
Location: http://localhost:8080/hazardlift-1.0-SNAPSHOT/
Line Number 8, Column 25:<td><m:nick></m:nick></td>
-----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe lift doesn't get how to handle your return value. Try forcing an implicit conversion to NodeSeq by specifing it as returntype.

```
....
def list(xhtml: NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = 
....
```

Comment: That worked, thanks alot.

How could one discover that in a good way? The error was not really helpfull...

Comment: An exception should direct you to the log.

You'll probably see in your log that there was a failure trying to match the snippet. It's standard that snippets need return types, so that should prompt you to check the type signature on your snippet delcaration.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another cause of this error - an unresolved tag.

I had this HTML:

```
<div >
    <h3>Request Information</h3>

    <lift:DetailedRequestData.renderContent>
        <f:rowTag></f:rowTag>
    </lift:DetailedRequestData.renderContent>
</div>
```

I had written this for `renderContent`:

```
def renderContent(ns: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
  val key = beginTrans(DisplayData.logger)
  var result = ns

  try {
    var requestID = DisplayData.getParameter("request")
    bind("f", ns, "rowTag" -> <p>Request ID: {requestID}</p>)
  }
  catch {
    case t: Throwable => DisplayData.logger.error("[DetailedRequestData$.renderContent] ", t)
  }

  endTrans(DisplayData.logger, key)
  result
}
```

Since I had not assigned the result of the `bind` to `result`, I was returning the unmodified `NodeSeq` and got the same `prefix not bound to a namespace` error. Changing the one statement to:

```
    result = bind("f", ns, "rowTag" -> <p>Request ID: {requestID}</p>)
```

Yes, this was my own stupid fault, but by documenting the problem here, hopefully I will save someone else from having this same problem and not knowing why.